# nginx reload config with multiple servers

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm serving some demos in isolation like:

```
/demo1/-- nginx.conf
       |- index.html
       |- ...

#run
/demo1$ sudo nginx -c `pwd`/nginx.conf
```

and

```
/demo2/-- nginx.conf 
       |- index.html
       |- ...

#run
/demo2$ sudo nginx -c `pwd`/nginx.conf
```

now I have the following nginx processes:

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root      3434  0.0  0.0  85904  1340 ?        Ss   12:02   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /demo1/nginx.conf
nobody     3435  0.0  0.0  86316  2272 ?        S    12:02   0:00 nginx: worker process                                                 
root      5096  0.0  0.0  85904  1344 ?        Ss   11:21   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /demo2/nginx.conf
nobody     5097  0.0  0.0  86316  2272 ?        S    11:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

I believe (tell me if I'm wrong) that if I reload the configuration this way:

```
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

It will only deliver the message to the last master process that was spun.

How do I reload the configuration on a specific master process?
After reading the [manpage](http://www.rootr.net/man/man/nginx/8) I believe it has some to do with the `-g` option but I'm not sure how. Should I specify a static PID or something?

Here is my `nginx.conf` for reference

```
user nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen      8000;
        location / {
            root    /demoX;
            index   index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a signal to certain PID:

kill -QUIT 3434

Reload option is a reference to QUIT signal which reloads the config and spawn new worker.

Comment: can I make a reference to the global PID directive from a config file?

Comment: @Reno it is prefer to save PID in the certain file and make: kill -QUIT $(cat /demo1/nginx.pid)